# Create dynamic folder using SQL*Plus

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, sqlplus

I need to create directory in Linux with date stamp from SQL*Plus. Is there a command that can be run in *.sql file to create a directory with current date?

Comment: No you don't. You are trying to solve the wrong problem. Just create the directory from your bash script.

Answer (score 1):

The SQL*Plus command you're looking for is `host`. It allows you to run a Linux shell command, so

```
host mkdir $(date +%F);
```

Adjust the date format as necessary (`man date` will help you with that).

Answer (score 1):

As I already said, you are trying to solve the wrong problem. So here it is, using a script:

```
[oracle@o71 ~]$ ls -l
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall 129 Feb  3 12:35 script.sh
[oracle@o71 ~]$ cat script.sh
export SPOOLDIR=$(date +%F)
mkdir $SPOOLDIR
sqlplus -S / as sysdba <<EOF
spool $SPOOLDIR/output.txt
select * from dual;
exit
EOF
[oracle@o71 ~]$ ./script.sh

D
-
X

[oracle@o71 ~]$ ls -l
total 4
drwxr-xr-x. 2 oracle oinstall  24 Feb  3 12:35 2019-02-03
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 oracle oinstall 129 Feb  3 12:35 script.sh
[oracle@o71 ~]$ ls -l 2019-02-03/
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 oracle oinstall 245 Feb  3 12:35 output.txt
[oracle@o71 ~]$ cat 2019-02-03/output.txt

D
-
X

[oracle@o71 ~]$
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried above and it works fine. however, when i try to call  .sql file from script.sh, i keep getting error" not spooling currently"
export SPOOLDIR=$(date +%F)
mkdir $SPOOLDIR
sqlplus -S / as sysdba  @daily.sql<<EOF
spool $SPOOLDIR/output.csv
daily.sql file  

 set markup csv on
@daily.sql 
spool off
  exit

Comment: only issue i am having now is with file permissions. I can't change the permission of  Spooled out files in script.sh